# How to get more granular results with cProfile

Tags: python, profiling

I have a little snippet which I'm profiling, however the `list comprehension` is listed as one item in the calls

```
import fileinput
import cProfile

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
x = [float(i) for i in range(0, 10**8)]
pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='time')
```

**Output**:

```
     2 function calls in 19.769 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   19.769   19.769   19.769   19.769 sandboxMinimalCProfile.py:6(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Is it possible to get for example what the cost was to convert to `float` ?

Comment: I'm not sure about `cProfiler`, but you can use [`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) for this kind of thing.

Comment: Although actually, I don't think it will do single calls in a list comprehension. You could use `timeit` for things like that? And for a single aggregated time, you'd just divide the whole time by `10**8`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `float` is a builtin, so they don't count as calls for the profiler.

You can try to workaround it; however, the profiler is not designed for micro-benchmarks in any case. Instead, try the [`timeit` standard module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
$ python3 -m timeit 'float(1000000)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.118 usec per loop
```